EF: Query a column marked as NotMapped
In an EF DataContext within a WinForms applicationn I have multiple tables all with the same layout: ID, Description. However, the ID field has different names in every table ("ProductTypeID", "SubTypeID", "ProducerID", ...).
I wanted to use a single form to do CRUD operations on such tables  so this is what I did:
ProductType.cs, SubType.cs, Producer.cs, etc.
[Table("ProductType")]
public class ProductType : IGenericTable
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ProductTypeID { get; set; } = -1; // the name of this property is different in every table
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public int ID { get => ProductTypeID; set => ProductTypeID = value; } // used in generic form
}

IGenericTable.cs
internal interface IGenericTable
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

GenericForm.cs
internal partial class GenericForm<T> : Form where T : class, IGenericTable, new()
{
    // T.Description property is bound to a textbox.

    private BindingSource bs = new();
    private MODataContext dc;

    public T Item { get => (T)bs.Current; }

    public GenericForm(MODataContext dc, T item)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        if (item == null) item = new();

        bs.DataSource = item;

        this.dc = dc;
    }

    private void cmdOK_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        var cur = (T)bs.Current;

        if (cur.ID == -1) dc.Set<T>().Add(cur);

        dc.SaveChanges();

        this.Close();
    }
}

This way I can reuse the same form to create and edit records from all the different tables. I do something similar to query and delete records.
I wanted to add a check in cmdOK_Click for already existing records with the same description, so I tried this:
    private void cmdOK_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        var cur = (T)bs.Current;

        var set = dc.Set<T>();

        if (set.Any(x => x.ID != cur.ID && x.Description == txtDescription.Text.Trim())) // EXCEPTION HERE
        {
            MessageBox.Show("A record with the same description already exists!", "Warning!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            return;
        }

        if (cur.ID == -1) dc.Set<T>().Add(cur);

        dc.SaveChanges();

        this.Close();
    }

However this code throws the following exception:
System.NotSupportedException: 'The specified type member 'ID' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.'
I think this is because the ID column is not mapped to a column in db.
Provided that I cannot change db column names, I tried to associate both the specific and generic ID columns to the same column in db, but this is not permitted:
// This does not work

[Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity), Column("ProductTypeID")]
public int ProductTypeID { get; set; } = -1; // the name of this property is different in every table
public string Description { get; set; }

[Column("ProductTypeID")]
public int ID { get => ProductTypeID; set => ProductTypeID = value; } // used in generic form

In this case EF complains that I can't have two properties mapped to the same column.
Any clue?

It is EF Core or EF6? Are you OK, to use third party libraries, which chan help to execute such queries?

Each IGenericTable can have its ID mapped directly to a specific column name. Why don't you go that path?

if (set.Any(x => x.ID != cur.ID && x.Description == txtDescription.Text.Trim()))

You can't use NotMapped for your Any() query. Get data records before filtering through using set.ToList() statement
Or use Computed column , whose value is computed every time it is fetched from the database.
modelBuilder.Entity<Entity>()
    .Property(p => p.ID)
    .HasComputedColumnSql("[ProductTypeID]");

